# show a preview of another form of application in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms application that has two forms first one is a control panel, and the other one is a full-screen form showing on an extended display. I'm trying to show a view of the extended display in my control panel like this :

control Pnanel

[image: Control Panel View]

Extended Display

[image: Extended Display]

I don't know how to achieve this, so please point me in the right direction and tell me what should I be looking for.

I didnt find anything related to this in google (probably searching wrong) any tip can help

Comment: Sounds like your trying to capture the frames of the extended display and display them in the control panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the code below to get a preview of another windows forms application  inside your current windows forms application like in this picture.
[image]
This is just like trying to mirror a second windows forms app screen and display it in the primary windows forms app.

```
var form = new Display();
form.Show();
//start capturing frames from it and display in the picture boc
Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
form.DrawToBitmap(bmpScreenshot, new Rectangle(0, 0, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height));
bmpScreenshot.Save("screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "screenshot.png";
```